# gmake: turn all %.c and %.cxx in variable to lib%.a lib%.so

Tags: gnu-make

My makefile creates a number of small libraries, in `.a` and `.so` form, from single `.c` and `.cxx` files.  For instance, if `SmallLibSrc` includes a `foo.c` I want `SmallLibs` to include `libfoo.a libfoo.so`.  Likewise if `SmallLibSrc` includes a `bar.cxx` I want `SmallLibs` to include `libbar.a libbar.so`.

I can get this to work in two steps by using a dummy variable such as:

```
SmallLibsDummyA  = $(SmallLibSrc:%.c=lib%.a)
SmallLibsDummySO = $(SmallLibSrc:%.c=lib%.so)
SmallLibs        = $(SmallLibsDummyA:%.cxx=lib%.a) $(SmallLibsDummySO:%.cxx=lib%.so)
```

But for some reason doing it in one variable fails.  I think I'm not understanding something about the syntax of these substitutions.  Is there another one-line approach that'd work?  Note I'm asking in part for a cleaner solution but mainly to learn more about $().

```
SmallLibs = $($(SmallLibSrc:%.cxx=lib%.a):%.c=lib%.a) $($(SmallLibSrc:%.cxx=lib%.so):%.c=lib%.so)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work:

```
SmallLibSrc = foo.cxx bar.c

$($(SmallLibSrc:%.cxx=lib%.a):%.c=lib%.a)
```

because the format of substitution variables is `$(NAME:...)` where `NAME` is a variable *name*.  In your example first the inner variable is expanded and you get:

```
SmallLibSrc = foo.cxx bar.c

$(libfoo.a bar.c:%.c=lib%.a)
```

It will try to expand the make *variable* named `libfoo.a bar.c` which clearly doesn't exist.

You can't use this form; you'll have to use the more generic function, like this:

```
$(foreach base,$(basename $(SmallLibSrc)),lib$(base).a lib$(base).so)
```